# Remoting facilities on Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, remoting

I'm toying with my first remoting project and I need to create a RemotableType DLL. I know I can compile it by hand with csc, but I wonder if there are some facilities in place on Visual Studio to handle the Remoting case, or, more specificly, to tell it that a specific file should be compiled as a .dll without having to add another project to a solution exclusively to compile a class or two into DLLs.

NOTE: I know I should toy with my first WCF project, but this has to run on 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get away with just calling csc.exe on the pre-build event if you don't want to mess with the .proj file directly and add build events.

Answer (score 0):

None that I know of using VS 2008 at the moment.

But you might want to check out **[NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/)**. It is made for this kind of work.